# PHP - Object cloning

Tags: php, clone, cloning

I want to pass a clone of `$this->user->settings` to function `$this->updateUser`, so the original array will not be affected.

```
private function updateSettings($field, $value)
{
  echo gettype($this->user->settings); // array
  $this->user->settings[$field] = $value;
  $this->updateUser('settings', json_encode($this->user->settings));
  echo gettype($this->user->settings); // string
}
```

What is the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: use the keyword clone to clone the object if you are in need of object cloning

Comment: keyword clone stops the script for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following:

```
private function updateSettings($field, $value)
{
    $newArray = array_merge($this->user->settings, [$field => $value]);

    $this->updateUser('settings', json_encode($newArray));
}
```

Btw, [object cloning](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) is another thing and in this case it's not that.